# If I uninstall my disc copy of Train Simulator 2013, will the activation code still work in Steam when I reinstall it?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, train-simulator-2013

My girlfriend just bought me a disc copy of Train Simulator 2013. While it initially worked fine, the game now is quoting "unable to load - scenario.bin".

I have verified all files through Steam, but it is still not loading scenarios.

If I uninstall the game and then reinstall it from CD, will the activation code still work?

Comment: By 'rs-2014', do you mean 'Train Simulator 2013'? If not, please edit your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

The activation code is now tied to your Steam account, so it will not work. What will likely happen is that the game will check your account, and then start downloading the complete game again (which is quite large if you have any of the DLC... last time I played it was taking up about 50GB).

To re-install from the disc, follow the instructions found [here on the Steam support site](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5357-FSQM-0382), though be aware that there'll be several patches that need to be downloaded (including possible the transition from TS2013 to TS2014).

A more productive use of your time, and bandwidth, would be to try and figure out what is going wrong when loading the scenarios. Do you get a specific error message?